# How to use local push notification in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am making a game using cocod2d-x, i am a beginner so i don't know how to push local notification in my game.
Can you help me resolve this problem?
Thanks all.

Comment: Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Local notifications are NOT push, thus should not be called "push local notification" which might be confusing. There are local notifications and push notifications, nothing else, at this point.

Answer (score 0):

to set a local notification in Ios, you have to edit applicationDidEnterBackground method in  your appcontroller.mm class.. take a look at the code below...

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {


    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    //NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    //NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:now];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:now];

    // Set up the fire time

    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]+_notificationTimeMinutes];
    [dateComps setSecond:([timeComponents second]+_notificationTimeSeconds)];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    localNotif.alertBody=@"Your local notification message";
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";
    NSLog(@"setAlarm Called : %@",itemDate);
    //localNotif.hasAction = NO;
    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber+1;
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
    //[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber += 1;
    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
```

In above code _notificationTimeSeconds is in seconds and _notificationTimeMinutes is in minutes similarly you can add hours and days or months after which you want your notification to appear.. you add your message in "your local notification message"